# Odds for straight or flush on the flop

Tags: odds, flush, straight

What are the odds of hitting a straight or a flush on the flop with 2 suited cards that are max 3 cards apart, meaning:

A2s, A3s, A4s, A5s, 23s, 23s, 24s, 25s, 34s .... AKs

Answer (score 1):

Well. They are definitely not the same for each of those combinations.

56s is more likely to hit a straight or a flush than A5s.

With any two suited cards, you hit a flush 11/50 x 10/49 x 9/48 = 0,84% of the time (roughly)

With a three-gapper like A5 or 59, you hit a straight 4/50 * 4/49 * 4/48 * 3! = 0,27% of the time.

Can't really perform the calculations by hand on more complicated things like connectors hitting a straight right now, but some software nerd will probably help here